# ServiceStack logging FluentValidation errors on server eventlog

Tags: logging, servicestack

I use the built in LogManager of service stack with event log as target.
Also I use the built in FluentValidation.

Both are working really nice. But when a Validation Error occurs, no logentry is created.

Any hint how I can log validation errors of any registered validator of the fluentvalidation?

Normal logs are working (like the one on the bottom of the configure Method)

Here my configure Method

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

            //Configure User Defined REST Paths
            Routes
              .Add<ProcessKilnPushRequest>("/kiln/commit");

            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

            container.RegisterValidators(typeof(KilnCommitService).Assembly);

            //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));


            LogManager.LogFactory = new EventLogFactory("QAServer.Logging", "KilnListener");

            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());

            logger.Info("AppHost up and running");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times Logs are retrieved and initialized in static constructors so to ensure that all components retrieved the configured logger you should set it before initializing the AppHost, e.g in Global.asax.cs:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new EventLogFactory("QAServer.Logging", "KilnListener");
new AppHost().Init()
```

Comment: Well the logger is working, but I don't know how to setup it up to log the validation exceptions from the fluent validation plugin...